# NVidia Physx Get Orientation problem

Tags: c++, glm, physx

For a game that I am developing I moved from Bullet physics to NVidia Physx. The problem that I have is the following. I used to have a translation from bullet's rigid body orientation quaternion to Front , Right and Up vector for each object on the screen. This was working fine but after I moved to Physx I noticed that there is only one quaternion in the transform of the object (probably representing rotation) and no orientation quaternion. Here is the code that I was using in Bullet to get the 3 vectors translated to Physx :

```
physx::PxQuat ori = mBody->getGlobalPose().q;

auto Orientation = glm::quat(ori.x, ori.y, ori.z, ori.w);

glm::quat qF = Orientation * glm::quat(0, 0, 0, 1) * glm::conjugate(Orientation);
glm::quat qUp = Orientation * glm::quat(0, 0, 1, 0) * glm::conjugate(Orientation);
front = { qF.x, qF.y, qF.z };
up = { qUp.x, qUp.y, qUp.z };
right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(front, up));
```

This apparently doesn't work for Physx. Is there another way to retrieve the 3 vectors from the rigid body ?

Comment: Your code seems to be mixed up about which argument to `glm::quat()` is the real component (w) and which are the imaginary components (x, y z). `glm::quat(ori.x, ori.y, ori.z, ori.w)` this says the `w` component is last, but this `lm::quat qF = Orientation * glm::quat(0, 0, 0, 1) * ...` says the `w` component is first, and the last argument must be `z`.

Comment: Good observation, but still the orientation of the body is wrong :(. Thanks though

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us 1) your modified code 2) a description of what specific wrong behaviour you get when you use that code 3) a test case of the form "I set the rotation like this, and I read the quaternion and get this, and then I get these basis vectors, but I expected these other basis vectors instead"

Comment: I confirm your suggestion is the one that fixes the problem ( I have more problems with other calculations at the moment and got confused). I need to set glm::quat(w,x,y,z). If you make it an answer I will accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this line:

```
glm::quat qF = Orientation * glm::quat(0, 0, 0, 1) * glm::conjugate(Orientation);
```

It looks like glm::quat() is taking arguments in the order `w, x, y, z` (ie. real component first, then the three imaginary components), so that `glm::quat(0, 0, 0, 1)` represents a pure imaginary quaternion (a 3D vector) pointing along the z+ axis.

But this line puts `w` last instead of first:

```
auto Orientation = glm::quat(ori.x, ori.y, ori.z, ori.w);
```

This should probably be like this instead, to match the convention used elsewhere in your code:

```
auto Orientation = glm::quat(ori.w, ori.x, ori.y, ori.z);
```